# Appending data-frames to excel file with different number of Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have Few CSV files with Different number of Columns (For Example a CSV file will be having 10 columns and another maybe having 5 columns.) and all the CSV file is having column header in it. Now let's Say I am having 10 CSV file having 10 Columns and another 10 CSV files having 5 Columns. I have a code which keeps watching on a folder, And when I drop a CSV file into that folder for the first time, it gets into the panda's data frame and from there I write the data frame into Excel file. Now I don't want the header of All CSV files to be kept into Excel file as 10 CSV files having 10 Columns are having the same column header. So the first thing is I want the header only Once in my Excel file. Now I want to append Data to existing excel file with CSV file data having only five columns. But this time columns number had come down from 10 to 5 so I need to print the column header again into Excel file. Any Idea Hows That possible?

I want an excel file like this from CSV files

[image]

This is my Main File

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import  Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import pandas as pd
from Append_Function import append_df_to_excel
import os.path
import sys


class Watcher:
    def __init__(self, args):
        self.watch_dir = os.getcwd()
        print(args[0])
        self.directory_to_watch = os.path.join(self.watch_dir, args[1])
        self.observer = Observer()

    def run(self):
        event_handler = Handler()
        self.observer.schedule(event_handler, self.directory_to_watch, recursive=True)
        self.observer.start()
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(5)
        except:
            self.observer.stop()
            print("Error")

        self.observer.join()

class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    header_List = []

    @staticmethod
    def on_any_event(event, i=0):
        if event.is_directory:
            return None
        elif event.event_type == 'created':
            # Take any action here when a file is first created.
            print("Received created event - %s." % event.src_path)
            #if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "myfile.xlsx")):
                #df = pd.read_csv(event.src_path, header=1, index_col=0)
            #else:
            df = pd.read_csv(event.src_path, header=0, index_col=0)


            append_df_to_excel(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "myfile.xlsx"), df)
        elif event.event_type == 'modified':
            # Taken any action here when a file is modified.
            print("Received modified event - %s." % event.src_path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(sys.argv)
    w = Watcher(sys.argv)
w.run()
```

This is My Append Function File

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl as ox


def append_df_to_excel(filename, df, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=None,
                       truncate_sheet=False,
                       **to_excel_kwargs):
    # ignore [engine] parameter if it was passed

    if 'engine' in to_excel_kwargs:
        to_excel_kwargs.pop('engine')

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl')

    # Python 2.x: define [FileNotFoundError] exception if it doesn't exist
    try:
        FileNotFoundError
    except NameError:
        FileNotFoundError = IOError

    try:
        # try to open an existing workbook
        writer.book = ox.load_workbook(filename)

        # get the last row in the existing Excel sheet
        # if it was not specified explicitly
        if startrow is None and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
            startrow = writer.book[sheet_name].max_row

        # truncate sheet
        if truncate_sheet and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
            # index of [sheet_name] sheet
            idx = writer.book.sheetnames.index(sheet_name)
            # remove [sheet_name]
            writer.book.remove(writer.book.worksheets[idx])
            # create an empty sheet [sheet_name] using old index
            writer.book.create_sheet(sheet_name, idx)

        # copy existing sheets
        writer.sheets = {ws.title: ws for ws in writer.book.worksheets}
    except FileNotFoundError:
        # file does not exist yet, we will create it
        pass

    if startrow is None:
        startrow = 0

    # write out the new sheet
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, startrow=startrow, **to_excel_kwargs)

    # save the workbook
    writer.save()
```

This is the Output of this Code
[image]
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Very easily done, share your code and what you've tried so far and what's failed

Comment: @Datanovice Sure Ill be Sharing Code Into my original Post

Comment: @Datanovice I have Added the Code as well as its output.

Comment: In your df to excel try header=False, this should get your desired result

Comment: @Datanovice all headers are being removed ...I want the header.

Comment: Can you show an example of your input data?